# Firebase Storage Exception "The storage Uri cannot contain a path element."

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This issue is arising by this line.

`val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance() .getReference(senderRoom.plus("/Media/Picture/".plus(imageName)))`

*imageName: "1695929588446"*

I don't know how but this exact code was giving no issue till yesterday but it's now giving this exception from nowhere.

The exception I'm getting is here

> The storage Uri cannot contain a path element.

I tried removing path inside the reference object and just for sake of testing passed only fileName
`val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance() .getReference(imageName)`

but still same exception.

Tried in this manner too but no luck
`val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance() .getReference().child(senderRoom.plus("/Media/Picture/".plus(imageName)))`

My firebase storage dependency:
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReference(senderRoom.plus("/Media/Picture/".plus(imageName)))
```

I changed it to:

```
val storageReference = Firebase.storage("gs://talkify-bd23c.appspot.com/")
                .getReference(senderRoom.plus("/Media/Picture/".plus(imageName)))
```

I don't know why this is even a problem because Firebase Cloud Storage documentation says that we can use both ways but apparently the above one not working for me since yesterday. It was working fine before.